# jFrog Artifactory: How to get a URL to display txt file contents in the browser

Tags: artifacts, artifactory

I have a system that stashes log reports in to Artifactory and send out a link to the report. Right now the link I send is of the form:
https://my-artifactory:/artifactory/my_repo/reports/some_topic/2022/02/11145845.txt

When this is opened in a browser, the file is offered as a download. However it'd be much nicer if it would display directly in the browser instead. Is there an alternative URL I can use or a setting in Artifactory that will enable this functionality? Seems there are a few related questions online but no clear answers about it.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the settings for MIME types? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Configuration+Descriptors

Comment: @mikequentel that's helpful, but not really. "Viewable" types defined in the mimetypes.xml can be viewed in the browser which is exactly what I want, except that I can't figure out a url I can send someone that will take them exactly to the view of the contents. Best I can find is a way to place them a couple of clicks away from viewing the contents, which is disappointing